# Powering multiple Raspberry Pi 4s with 65W USB-C computer charger

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-4, usb-c

Is it possible to power up multiple raspberry pi's with 65W USB-C computer charger? If so, is there anyone who have done it, that they can share how they did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a USB-C connector is limited to 3 Amperes or 15W at 5 Volts. Up to 5 Amperes is possible only with special high power cables and sockets.

Wattage above 15W is [always achieved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#PD) by using voltages higher than 5 V, and Raspberry Pi is a 5V only device with a regular 3A socket.